# avrdude : stk500_getsync not in sync:resp=0x87

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am using arduino uno r3 board and arduino 1.6.5 on windows 8. When Itried to upload my program on ATMEGA328 microcontroller it is showing:

> avrdude:stk500_getsync not in sync:resp=0x87.

help me to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to 3 problems usually..

1. The bootload on the chip is missing (unlikely if you purchased the board from Arduino).
2. The serial connection between the arduino and the computer is disconnected or interrupted.
3. You've simply selected the wrong board type or port when programming, and thus the IDE is searching for a signal that the arduino isn't coming back with.

This problem is most likely due to option 3, however it can occur in odd situations especially on the Arduino Micro where the board does all USB comms on chip and can be flooded by main without an appropriate delay to the point it can't communicate with the IDE. However this is just most likely a bad board selection or a bad port selection.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things but this worked for me. If you have a working Arduino lying around (in my case Uno) you can use it as an intermediate in-system programmer (ISP).

Follow this [guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Burn-a-Bootloader-to-Clone-Arduino-Nano-30/#step1) to first load the ISP sketch into your working Arduino.
Once you are done, for your non-working Arduino, select from the `Tools > Programmer` menu and choose `Arduino as ISP`, and set `Board` and `Processor` accordingly. To program choose `Sketch > Upload using programmer`.

Hope this works.

I *think* the reason that this work is that it will bypass the CH340/FTDI chip, and all those synchronization issue. Given that that is your problem.